# Laravel Mailable Headers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this issue and is that I need to set header to a Mail but not via `Mail::send()` I need to set the headers inside the Mailable Class that I created with
`php artisan make:mail`

Thanks a lot.

I'm using Laravel 5.3

Comment: Could you provide the code you currently try?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to use the `withSwiftMessage` method inside your mailable. You can pass this method a callback which receives the `Swift_Message` instance which you can use to set your headers.

In your `build` method you could have:

```
$this->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) {
    $headers = $message->getHeaders();
    $headers->addTextHeader('header-name', 'optional-value');
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly and was exactly what I needed!

Comment: @dacastro4 Glad I could help!

Answer (score 9):

Theres's also a slightly shorter syntax than that given in the accepted answer above:

```
$this->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) {
   $message->getHeaders()
           ->addTextHeader('header-name', 'header-value');
});
```

as per the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#customizing-the-swiftmailer-message)